How to Map “Termdebug” Shortcuts in Vim
I want to use F2 to enter Termdebug immediately.
It's convenient to put file's name after the command like: Termdebug xxx (which has complied with -g option)
My host is Windows 11 and use VMware, which contains Ubuntu 22.04 LTS version.
I use following command in ~/.vimrc:
nnoremap <F2> :call RunTermdebug()<CR>
function! RunTermdebug()
    let filename = expand('%:t:r')
        let e_f=fnameescape(filename)
    execute "Termdebug ".e_f
endfunction

But it failed. The vim console shows that the result will become RunTermdebug()
If I change like this:
function! RunTermdebug()
    let filename = expand('%:t:r')
    execute "Termdebug"." ".filename
endfunction

Still doesn't work, the same result as above.
If I change like this:
function! RunTermdebug()
    let filename = expand('%:t:r')
    execute "Termdebug".filename
endfunction

The command seems like: Termdebugxxx, but I need blank between them.
I also use \ or <space> but it still doesn't work.
Is there any nice plugin, software or method you are using or recommend?

Your first mapping works as expected. What do you mean by "The vim console shows that the result will become RunTermdebug()"? What error do you get, exactly?

@romainl I mean if I use this command I will see the output "RunTermdebug()" in the Vim console.
Because I tried to simulate the command to execute "Termdebug xxx", I should see Termdebug xxx" instead of "RunTermdebug()" in the console.
However, is there any better method to achieve my function? Thanks :)

Your mapping works and there is no better method. Also what do you call "the vim console"?
